# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'EntryType'

Tags: c++, constructor, enums

I'm getting this error, and I don't know why. I got part of the code from Mark Allen Weiss' book. He makes his `hashEntry` struct the exact same way (I used different names though). Am I doing something wrong using `enum` or forgetting to include something?

```
#ifndef QHASHTABLE
#define QHASHTABLE

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

class quadraticHashTable
{
public:
    explicit quadraticHashTable(int size = 101)
    : hashArray(nextPrime(size)), currentSize{0}
    { makeEmpty(); };           

    bool contains(const int & searchItem);
    void makeEmpty();
    bool insert(const int & insertItem);
    bool remove(const int & removeItem);
    int getCurrentSize();
    void testDisplay() const;

    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED }; //ACTIVE = 0, EMPTY = 1, DELETED = 2

private:
    struct hashEntry
    {
        int value;
        EntryType status;

        hashEntry(const int & v = int{}, EntryType s = EMPTY)  //ERROR HERE
        : value( v ), status( s ){}
    };

    size_t hashFunction(int value);
    bool isActive(int currentPos) const;
    int findPos(const int & value);
    void reHash();
    void reHashDelete();

    vector<hashEntry> hashArray;
    int currentSize;
};
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Clearly the problem is the `= int{}` syntax, which I guess is some C++11 thing. Anything wrong with `hashEntry(int v = 0, EntryType s = EMPTY)`? Using a reference to an int seems strange to me.

Comment: @john yeah that seemed strange to me too. But on this page you can his code: http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaa_c++4/code/QuadraticProbing.h    He uses a template though, so I just switched 'HashObj' with 'int'. Anyways, I fixed it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Ghost_Stark You can also change `= int{}` to `= int()`, which in this case will have the same result and will compile without any problems. By the way, the code you linked could be improved *a lot*.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek email him. That code is in his Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis book. Not sure if your optimizations would be suitable in the context of what he's covering though.